# Is there a way to make an Installshield 2015 installer always run silent without a command line?

Tags: installshield-le

I've searched all over and have not found this. I need to make an Installshield 2015 installer that just installs unattended. No next clicking, no finish button to click, just installs and closes. I don't care if it is visible or not. No using a command line switch.

Comment: Why exactly command line switch is not an option?

Comment: It's a deployment restriction based on a number of reasons i can't get into. Believe me i'd rather just use a switch it would make life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation i figured out a way to do it.

1. Unload the VS installer project.
2. Open the .isl file in your text editor of choice located in the installer projects folder
3. Do a search for InstallUISequence
4. Remove the following lines from the section:

   ```
   <row><td>InstallWelcome</td><td>Not Installed</td><td>1210</td><td>InstallWelcome</td><td/></row>
   <row><td>SetupCompleteError</td><td/><td>-3</td><td>SetupCompleteError</td><td/></row>
   <row><td>SetupCompleteSuccess</td><td/><td>-1</td><td>SetupCompleteSuccess</td><td/></row>
   ```

   - You can optionally remove this if you want no progress bar:

     ```
     <row><td>SetupProgress</td><td/><td>1240</td><td>SetupProgress</td><td/></row>
     ```
5. Save the file in the text editor
6. Reload the project in visual studio and build the file.